# Cannot configure multiple data sources using Grails 3 and MySql

Tags: mysql, grails-3.0

The docs are pretty straightforward for [creating multiple datasources](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.9/guide/conf.html#multipleDatasources) using Grails 3, however I cannot get it to work.

When I configure a second datasource, even if I don't use it anywhere in the code, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'dataSource' is defined
```

which leads me to believe I have an error in my application.yml file. Here's the relevant code:

```
dataSources:
    dataSource:
        pooled: true
        jmxExport: true
        driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        dialect: "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"
    lookup:
        driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        dialect: "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"

environments:
    development:
        dataSources:
            dataSource:
                dbCreate: create-drop
                url: jdbc:mysql://localhost/maindb?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
                username: "root"
                password: "fakepwd"

        lookup:
            dbCreate: create-drop
            url: jdbc:mysql://localhost/docreds?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
            username: "root"
            password: "fakepwd"
    test:
        dataSources:
            dataSource:
                dbCreate: update
                url: jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=9000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE

    production:
        dataSources:
            dataSource:
                dbCreate: update
                url: jdbc:h2:./prodDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=8000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
                properties:
                    jmxEnabled: true
                    initialSize: 5
                    maxActive: 50
                    minIdle: 5
                    maxIdle: 25
                    maxWait: 10000
                    maxAge: 600000
                    timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
                    minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
                    validationQuery: SELECT 1
                    validationQueryTimeout: 3
                    validationInterval: 15000
                    testOnBorrow: true
                    testWhileIdle: true
                    testOnReturn: false
                    jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState
                    defaultTransactionIsolation: 2 # TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
```

Removing **dataSources** and the associated definitions brings the application to a working state

Comment: Did you find solution to the question? I am having same issue